# DropDownListFor pick an item and make it selected

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am generating a drop down list for languages. I want to make a specific item of that list as `selected`. Here is the view page code:

```
@{var languageList = new List<SelectListItem>();
    var cultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);

    foreach (var culture in cultures)
    {
        if(culture.NativeName != "Invariant Language (Invariant Country)")
        {
            languageList.Add(new SelectListItem {
                Text = (culture.EnglishName != culture.NativeName) ?
                       culture.EnglishName + " - " + culture.NativeName :
                       culture.EnglishName,
                Value = culture.EnglishName.Contains('(') ?
                        culture.EnglishName.Split('(')[0].ToString().Trim() :
                        culture.EnglishName
            });
        }
    }
    languageList.OrderBy(x => x.Value);  
}
```

Now if I call that list like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language, languageList, "English", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Then it will not select the `English` value. It will simple create a new text `English` with value `null` and set it to the top of the list. This is good when we want to use something like `--Select Item--`. But I want to make that specific item selected whose value is `English` and text is `English (United States)`. How do I do it?

Comment: you need to set the Language property in the get action method and pass model to view

Comment: Well here is the problem. In that list there are multiple items whose value is `English` but they have different text like `English (Caribbean)` or `English (Europe)` etc. If I set the Language property from controller, then in view; all those items gets selected and the last one shows.

Comment: then you have wrong data, you need to have text as well same, otherwise how it will know which to be selected

Comment: The `Language` property is actually a `string`. I am generating this list from `CulturInfo` so these data are kinda default. I know whichever `English Language` is selected the value of it will always be `English`. So unless I use javascript to manually select the item with text `English (United States)`, I really cant find any other way. And I was hoping that I could avoid javascript for this single matter.

Comment: but you can have same logic for `Text` and `Value`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
languageList.Add(new SelectListItem
{
    Text = (culture.EnglishName != culture.NativeName) ?
            culture.EnglishName + " - " + culture.NativeName : culture.EnglishName,
    Value = culture.EnglishName.Contains('(') ?culture.EnglishName.Split('(')0].ToString().Trim() : culture.EnglishName,
    Selected = (culture.EnglishName == "English (United States)") ? true : false
});
```

You can use derloopkat's solution also.

Answer (score 1):

Set the selected item when populating the list:

```
var defaultListItem = new SelectListItem()
{
    Text = "English (United States)",
    Value = "English",
    Selected = true
};
languageList.Add(defaultListItem);
```

So you don't need to specify selected in Html helper.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language, languageList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

This generates an option that looks like:

```
<option selected="selected" value="English">English (United States)</option>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the wrong overload of `DropDownListFor`, the "English" you are setting is for the default value if empty not the selected value. One way to resolve this issue would be to set the value in the SelectList:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language, new SelectList(languageList, "Value", "Text", "English") ,new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Although this could result in any of the items with value "English" being selected.

Comment: Good try but in his case there are many items with "English" value. Your code selects "English (Zimbabwe)".